# no such column while compiling SELECT statement

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am getting this error while executing my android app. I have created the SQLite database in a file called MySQLitehelper.java which has the following lines for creating the tables:

```
 public static final String COLUMN_ID = "GWid";
  public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "DateGWU";
  public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
  public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";
  
  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "UPDTable";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UPDdb_version6";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;
  
  private final Context context;
  GetSet getset = new GetSet();
  public void GetIdForGwid(GetSet get)
  {
     getset=get; 
  }
 
  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                                " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " integer," + COLUMN_DATE + "VARCHAR," +
                                COLUMN_LOCATION+" VARCHAR," +COLUMN_TIME +" VARCHAR);";
  
  private static final String DATABASE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +
                                                " Values (47688507,'DEC-07-2012','MARVIN 203','20:00');";
```

In the same file i have the statements that execute my SQL SELECT query but give me the exception no such column found DateGWU

```
public Cursor getRecord() throws SQLException
{
        Cursor mCursor =
        db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COLUMN_ID,
        COLUMN_DATE, COLUMN_LOCATION, COLUMN_TIME},
        COLUMN_ID + "= 47688507", null, null, null, null, null);   //HARDCODED. Please make it dynamic
        if (mCursor != null) 
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
 return mCursor;
 }
```

I'm kinda stuck and don't know where am I going wrong.

## LOGCAT

```
11-30 04:57:50.832: E/SQLiteLog(12912): (1) no such column: DateGWU
11-30 04:57:50.842: D/AndroidRuntime(12912): Shutting down VM
11-30 04:57:50.852: W/dalvikvm(12912): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: DateGWU (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT GWid, DateGWU, location, time FROM UPDTable WHERE GWid= '47688507'
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
11-30 04:57:50.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12912):    at com.example.upd.MySQLitehelper.getRecord(MySQLitehelper.java:125)
```

Comment: @ShreyaShah: type for Column_ID is integer. also I tried using '47688507', but error exists

Comment: db.query( TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COLUMN_ID,
        COLUMN_DATE, COLUMN_LOCATION, COLUMN_TIME},
        COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(47688507)},  null, null, null, null); i hope that is how the query is run

Comment: @noobcoder have you try my answer?

Comment: @Nik....: No change. Error still exists

Comment: @noobcoder have you tried my code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Change Database Insert Statement

```
private static final String DATABASE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +  " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " ," + COLUMN_DATE + "," +
                                COLUMN_LOCATION+" ," +COLUMN_TIME +" )"  +
                                                " Values (47688507,'DEC-07-2012','MARVIN 203','20:00');";
```

Comment: No change. Error still exists.

Comment: please clean project and try again.

Comment: Thanks man....It worked. I didn't get the reason behind it. But for now, it's working

Answer (score 7):

You have

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                            " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " integer," + COLUMN_DATE + "VARCHAR," +
                            COLUMN_LOCATION+" VARCHAR," +COLUMN_TIME +" VARCHAR);";
```

Change it to

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                            " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " integer," + COLUMN_DATE + " VARCHAR,"  +
                            COLUMN_LOCATION+" VARCHAR," +COLUMN_TIME +" VARCHAR);";
```

Notice the space:

> COLUMN_DATE + "VARCHAR,"
>
> COLUMN_DATE + " VARCHAR,"

Comment: @Robin Chander: Good catch bro. But same problem. my app shuts down unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your database name from "UPDdb_version6" to "UPDdb_version6.db" i.e

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UPDdb_version6";
```

To,

```
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UPDdb_version6.db";
```